# Kerberos Failing CentOS 7.5 Apache 2.4 Kerberos 5

Tags: centos7, kerberos, apache2.4

EDIT Oct 25 2018:  We were unable to resolve this and have stopped trying. Because other parts of our company use SAML, we are moving all of our sites/applications to a SAML SSO approach. Thank you all for your questions and assistance

Preamble: I'm aiming to get some direction on where to start looking to solve my problem.  Thank you all in advance for reading through this and providing any guidance!

[Edit] Testing has been performed with IE, Firefox, and Chrome.  On windows machines and Macs.  The results are the same:  all work against the old servers and all fail against the new servers.

Problem: Kerberos SSO is not working on new CentOS 7.5 servers. I am moving my websites to new servers, upgrading from CentOS 6.7 to CentOS 7.5.  In this move, I am also upgrading from Apache/2.2.15 to Apache/2.4.33.  All servers are all sitting behind a load balancer end point.

On all of my CentOS 6.7 machines, kerberos works.  On all of my 7.5 machines, it fails.

====System specifics====

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul  3 2018 11:33:42
```

====Output from apache error log====

```
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1643): kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[headers:debug] mod_headers.c(900): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1643): kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1400): Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1416): Client didn't delegate us their credential
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1444): Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.
[auth_kerb:debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1116): GSS-API major_status:00010000, minor_status:00000000
[auth_kerb:error] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: An unsupported mechanism was requested (, Unknown error)
[headers:debug] mod_headers.c(900): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[headers:debug] mod_headers.c(900): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://six.***********.com/sso
```

====apache vhost files====

conf/vhosts.d/site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Define vhost_name siteName
    Define vhost_home /path/to/site/home

    Include conf/vhosts.d/template.inc

</VirtualHost>
```

conf/vhosts.d/template.inc

```
<Directory "${vhost_home}/sso">
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Login"
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    KrbAuthoritative off
    KrbAuthRealms [list of realms removed for security]
    Krb5Keytab "/etc/krb5.keytab"
    KrbServiceName Any
    require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/login/anonlogin.php\"></html>"
</Directory>
```

====And some output from kinit and klist====

```
$ sudo kinit -V -t /etc/krb5.keytab HTTP/six.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM
keytab specified, forcing -k
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: HTTP/six.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM
Using keytab: /etc/krb5.keytab
kinit: Client 'HTTP/six.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM
Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

$ sudo klist -etk
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/one.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/two.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/three.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/four.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/five.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
3 09/27/2018 10:22:17 HTTP/six.***********.com@aaa.**********.COM (arcfour-hmac)
```

Happy to provide any additional information.

We have these new servers currently sitting behind a load balancer end point which works with kerberos and centos 6.7 and apache 2.2.  The keytab file is the same on the old and new servers.

Comment: `received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported` > Question 1: did the older Apache svcs accept NTLM, or just Kerberos ? Question 2: did you try only with (presumably obsolete) IE browsers, or also with Chrome / Firefox / Edge etc?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know much about web servers & load balancers, but I thought that Kerberos was about strong authentication of a specific client, on a specific machine, against a specific service on a specific server (w/ canonical DNS names required). Throwing a LB in between seems to defeat that purpose...

Comment: The exact same user on the exact same machine on the exact same browser works on old server behind load balancer but seconds later fails on new server behind same load balancer.

Comment: And tried with Firefox and Chrome both fine against old server and fail against new.

Comment: Is the keytab location the *same* for both old and new servers (as defined in conf/vhosts.d/template.inc)?  Make sure Apache on the new servers is pointed to the the right keytab.  Otherwise it will not be able to decrypt service Kerberos tickets and and as you've seen in the logs it will start making guesses about the token being NTLM.  On the new servers you also need to install: krb5-libs, krb5-workstation, and mod_auth_kerb for Apache to successfully do Kerberos.

Comment: Hey.  Thank you T-Heron.  Keytab is in same location for both old and new servers.  Apache on new is pointed to correct keytab file.  All libraries and software are properly installed.  We're looking at two things right now:  1 network traffic to see what's being sent where and by whom; so far we see nada between webserver machine and AD.  2.  the SPN was entered on the AD side as http/  instead of HTTP/;  we can't test this until Friday but are wondering about case sensitivity on the linux side as all other SPNs are HTTP/

Comment: We were unable to resolve this and have stopped trying.  Because other parts of our company use SAML, we are moving all of our sites/applications to a SAML SSO approach.  Thank you all for your questions and assistance.